# Stuck on Ramda composition

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm trying to transform the following input which is an array of JSON to expected output shown below. indexCols is also

```
var objects = ['{"ticker":"MSFT", "key": 2, "PX_LAST":100}',
               '{"ticker":"AAPL", "key": 3, "PX_LAST":100}',
               '{"ticker":"GOOG", "key": 4, "PX_LAST":100}']

/* Expected output
  [[id, '{"ticker":"MSFT",  "key": 2, "PX_LAST":100}', 'MSFT', 2 ]
    [id, '{"ticker":"AAPL", "key": 3, "PX_LAST":100}', 'AAPL', 3 ]
    [id, '{"ticker":"GOOG", "key": 4, "PX_LAST":100}', 'GOOG', 4 ]]
*/
var indexCols = ['ticker', 'key']

var transform = function(input, indexCols, id) {
  var fn2 = R.compose(R.flip(R.map)(indexCols), R.flip(R.prop), JSON.parse)
  var fn3 = R.map(R.compose(R.concat([id]), fn2))
  return fn3(objects)
}

transform(objects, indexCols, 100)
/* result : [[100, "MSFT", 2], [100, "AAPL", 3], [100, "GOOG", 4]] */
```

As you can see the result arrays are missing the second element which is the json string. I'm unable to weave that in a functional way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These look unnecessarily complex...

How about:

```
const objects = ['{"ticker":"MSFT", "key": 2, "PX_LAST":100}',
               '{"ticker":"AAPL", "key": 3, "PX_LAST":100}',
               '{"ticker":"GOOG", "key": 4, "PX_LAST":100}']
const indexCols = ['ticker', 'key', 'PX_LAST']

const pickIndeces = pipe(JSON.parse, props(indexCols))
const format = map(x => concat([x], pickIndeces(x)))
format(objects)
```

---

Note, `pipe`, `props`, `concat` and `map` are Ramda functions. So you can import them, like so:

```
const { concat, map, pipe, props } = R
```

Answer (score 1):

( I think there is a typo, instead of this: return fn3(objects) you probably mean this: return fn3(input) )

```
  var transform = function(input, indexCols, id) {
      var fn2 = R.compose(R.flip(R.map)(indexCols), R.flip(R.prop), JSON.parse);
      var valueToArray = R.flip(R.append)([]);
      var fn3 = R.map(R.compose(R.flatten, R.concat([id]), R.compose(R.ap([R.identity, fn2]), valueToArray)))
      return fn3(input)
    }
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jrzmda

You have to duplicate your input object (a->[a,a]), then you can operate on the second element as you like (fn2), just keep the first element untouched (identity), and, at the end, concat it all together.

Improvement 1: Is there a Ramda function for valueToArray ( a->[a] ) already?
Improvement 2: Is there a way to concat id *not nested* to get rid of the R.flatten?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `R.converge` so you can feed the string to concat and JSON.parse:

```js
var objects = ['{"ticker":"MSFT", "key": 2, "PX_LAST":100}',
               '{"ticker":"AAPL", "key": 3, "PX_LAST":100}',
               '{"ticker":"GOOG", "key": 4, "PX_LAST":100}']

/* Expected output
  [[id, '{"ticker":"MSFT",  "key": 2, "PX_LAST":100}', 'MSFT', 2 ]
    [id, '{"ticker":"AAPL", "key": 3, "PX_LAST":100}', 'AAPL', 3 ]
    [id, '{"ticker":"GOOG", "key": 4, "PX_LAST":100}', 'GOOG', 4 ]]
*/
var indexCols = ['ticker', 'key']

var transform = function(input, indexCols, id) {
  //Have to trick R.converge into making it think that JSON.parse only has 1 argument
  var fn2 = R.compose(R.flip(R.map)(indexCols), R.flip(R.prop), R.curryN(1, JSON.parse))
  var fn3 = R.map(R.compose(R.concat([id]), R.converge(R.concat, [Array, fn2])))
  return fn3(input) //typo shouldn't be objects
}

console.log(transform(objects, indexCols, 100))
/* result : [[100, "MSFT", 2], [100, "AAPL", 3], [100, "GOOG", 4]] */
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

An alternative could be to use:

```
R.ap(R.compose(R.concat, Array), fn2))
// concat <$> Array <*> fn2
// R.liftN(2, R.concat)(Array, fn2) is the same
```

Instead of:

```
R.converge(R.concat, [Array, fn2])
```

That way you don't run into `R.converge` issue where it's guessing `JSON.parse` has 2 arguments.

Comment: @Satish, the aplicative for functions is `f => g => x => f(x)(g(x))` and the map for functions is compose `f => g => f(g(x))` if you use the composed function as the first parameter for the aplicative you'd get `f => g => h => x => f(g(x))(h(x))` which is basically `liftA2` for functions.